# Find the explicit solution to tyy' − 1 = 0, y(1) = 4 and give the interval of validity.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the **explicit** solution to $tyy' − 1 = 0$, $y(1) = 4$ and give the interval
of validity.

$ty \frac{dy}{dt} - 1 = 0$

$y \frac{dy}{dt} - 1 = 0$ ==> $ydy - {1/t} dt = 0$

$ydy = 1/t dt$

$\frac{y^2}{2} = ln(t) + c$

$y = \sqrt{2ln(t) + c}$

applying $y(1) = 4$

so the **explicit** solution is:
$C = 4$

But I'm not sure how to get the interval of validity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your solution is $$ y = \sqrt{2\ln t + 16}$$ the maximal interval is $\frac1{e^8} < t <  \infty$ so that $2\ln t + 16 > 0.$

to find the interval of existence, first solve $2\ln t + 16 = 0$ for $t.$
you get $\ln t = -8$ which is equivalent to $t =e^{-8} = \dfrac1{e^8}.$ now use the fact that $\ln $ in increasing to conclude that $\ln(t) > -8$ for $1/e^8 < t < \infty.$

Comment: Can you show me steps to how you found the interval? Thanks

Comment: @user3325915, see my edit.

Comment: Abel, is my $C$ correct as well? Since $C$ is just an arbitrary constant  - I don't have to worry about the radical correct?

Comment: @user3325915, your $c$ inside the radical should be $16$ so that $y(1) = 4.$ you have an incorrect $c = 4.$

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't C be 16?
For the interval: you need that

- t$\not=$0, otherwise you can't divide for it
- t $>$ 0, otherwise $\ln{t}$ is not defined
- $2\ln{t} + C\geq0$

Comment: But $C$ is just a arbitrary constant right? Why would I put it under the radical, it shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: C depends by the initial condition y(t=1)=4, so $\sqrt{2\ln{1} + C} = \sqrt{C}=4$

Comment: Yes but $C$ is just an arbitrary constant so essentially it shouldn't matter if $C$ is under the radical.. Do you see what I'm saying? If that was the case then $C$ should also be multiplied by $2$..

Comment: If you derive respect t, you have: $$\frac{1}{t\sqrt{2\ln{t}+16}} = \frac{1}{ty}$$ so this is a solution. It is important that the constant is under the radical otherwise the first derivative is not defined in t=1 (and doesn't solve the equation).